# Only the last element of Recycler view being displayed after onclicklistener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to retrieve my data from server and then displaying it with the help of `RecyclerView`. My `RecyclerView` contains 4 buttons and each button sends the data to different tables. This is what i tried:

```
public class QuoteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<QuoteAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    List<QuoteList> qItems;
    String sQuote,sName,sEmail;
    public QuoteAdapter(List<QuoteList> qItems) {
        this.qItems = qItems;
    }

    @Override
    public QuoteAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fetch_list, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final QuoteAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final QuoteList codeListBeans = qItems.get(position);
        final Background background = new Background();
        holder.tv_quote.setText(codeListBeans.getQuote());
        holder.tv_name.setText(codeListBeans.getName());
        holder.tv_email.setText(codeListBeans.getEmail());
        sQuote=holder.tv_quote.getText().toString();
        sName=holder.tv_name.getText().toString();
        sEmail=holder.tv_email.getText().toString();

        holder.btn_other.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                url = "http://velapanti.esy.es/quotation/other/add.php";
                background.execute(sQuote, sEmail, sName);
            }
        });
        holder.btn_love.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                url = "http://velapanti.esy.es/quotation/love/add.php";
                background.execute(sQuote, sEmail, sName);
            }
        });
        holder.btn_mot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                url = "http://velapanti.esy.es/quotation/motivation/add.php";
                background.execute(sQuote, sEmail, sName);
            }
        });
        holder.btn_frnd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                url = "http://velapanti.esy.es/quotation/friends/add.php";
                background.execute(sQuote, sEmail, sName);
            }
        });

    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView tv_name, tv_quote, tv_email;
        public Button btn_other, btn_mot, btn_love, btn_frnd;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tv_quote = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_quote);
            tv_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            tv_email = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
            btn_frnd = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_frnd);
            btn_love = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_love);
            btn_mot = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_mot);
            btn_other = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_other);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return qItems.size();
    }

    class Background extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            if (isConnection()) {
                super.onPreExecute();
                progressDialog.show();
            } else {
                showConnectionErrorDialog();
                startActivity(getIntent());
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            sQuote = strings[0];
            sEmail = strings[1];
            sName = strings[2];

            try {
                URL openUrl = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) openUrl.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("quote", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(sQuote, "UTF-8")
                        + "&" +

                        URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(sEmail, "UTF-8")
                        + "&" +

                        URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(sName, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                OS.close();
                InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                IS.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return "Quotation Added";
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Snackbar.make(layout, result, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem that i am facing is when i click on any button the data from last row moves to the table regardless of the row from which i click the button i.e. if I click the button of any row the data from last row gets sent but not from the row that the button belongs to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is simple. In your `onBindViewHolder()` method you are getting `data`(`sQuote`, `sEmail`, `sName`) and storing them independently. Now when the `RecyclerView` finishes adding and setting data to all the `View`s your `data` containers are updated too, so that your `data` contains values from last `onBindView()` call.

That is to say if you were to scroll down and clicked you would send `data` from the `View`. Similarly if you were to scroll up you'd send data from the top most visible `View`.

You need to come up with a way so that your `data` remains updated.

Like instead of getting data from `sQuote`, etc. get data from `qItems`.

Also as a general rule don't create new objects in `onBindViewHolder()` especially listeners instead create them in either `onCreateViewHolder()` or in your `ViewHolder`. Because whenever you scroll back into a `View` another `Object` will be created.

For listeners that require position of the clicked `View` put them in `ViewHolder` (like in your case). So you can easily get the position of the clicked `View` by `getAdapterPosition()`.